# Keyboard shortcut to focus on docked dev tools. Chrome. OSX

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

Tried googling this with no success.

If I have the chrome dev tools docked to the right of my browser window and my focus is on the webpage, is there a keyboard shortcut to set my focus to the dev tools?

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> opens Chrome DevTools and focuses on it if its already opened.

Comment: When I try that when the dev tools are open it closes them.

Comment: Well, you might want to press it twice then.